# SharePoint group error: too many e-mail addresses were selected

Tags: 2013, groups

I have a SharePoint group with 82 members. Whenever I try to send an e-mail to all of my members the error appears: "Too many e-mail addresses were selected". I know there is only a limited length for URL. But is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the options mentioned here:

[Send email to all users in SharePoint group](https://sharepointumar.wordpress.com/2015/05/03/send-email-to-all-users-in-sharepoint-group/).